# Reality check using GLM

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I need a reality check if you will. I have a data set, where I know how many individual butterflies of two species co-occur at one meadow (not always, though). I have additional variables, for instance wet/dry meadow, intensely cultivated/not cultivated, percent of area around the meadow covered by wet or dry meadows...

This is the head of the dataset. 50 rows in total, 25 per species. Notice that all columns are identical except count and species, indicating that they come from the same sampling location.

```
> head(dej)
  count     type1 type2 perc.for.100m perc.dry.100m perc.wet.100m species
1     1 intensive   dry        13.836        22.724         0.000   reali
2     3 extensive   wet         6.877         1.613        52.213   reali
3     4 intensive   wet        22.770         0.537        44.901   reali
4     6 intensive   dry        17.346        42.322         6.359   reali
5     1 extensive   wet        34.854         9.091        11.950   reali
6     2 extensive   dry        50.387        19.245         0.000   reali
...
26     0 intensive   dry        13.836        22.724         0.000 sinapis
27     0 extensive   wet         6.877         1.613        52.213 sinapis
28     0 intensive   wet        22.770         0.537        44.901 sinapis
29     0 intensive   dry        17.346        42.322         6.359 sinapis
30     1 extensive   wet        34.854         9.091        11.950 sinapis
31     1 extensive   dry        50.387        19.245         0.000 sinapis
...
```

I'm interested in knowing if any of these variables influence the species and their respective counts.

And this is the result of the "full" model.

```
glm(formula = count ~ type1 + type2 + perc.for.100m + perc.dry.100m + 
    perc.wet.100m + species, family = poisson, data = dej)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.8458  -1.1414  -0.4546   0.8297   2.2145  

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)    0.028129   0.523509   0.054  0.95715   
type1intensive 0.196699   0.191960   1.025  0.30551   
type2wet       0.071841   0.334286   0.215  0.82984   
perc.for.100m  0.003741   0.008277   0.452  0.65130   
perc.dry.100m  0.010952   0.010750   1.019  0.30829   
perc.wet.100m  0.007467   0.011596   0.644  0.51960   
speciessinapis 0.597837   0.187689   3.185  0.00145 **
```

Does this sound like the correct approach at all?

*Some additional information*

As a side note, based on my exploration of the data, I would expect that the count would depend (at least) on the type2 variable, alas that's not what I got.

[image]

Using the "reverse logic", I tried if species can be predicted using my data, which presumably confirms the above results.

```
Call:
glm(formula = species ~ type1 + type2 + perc.for.100m + perc.dry.100m + 
    perc.wet.100m + count, family = binomial, data = dej)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.6322  -1.0136  -0.1568   1.0592   1.6407  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)    -0.351192   1.658052  -0.212   0.8323  
type1intensive -0.170583   0.651611  -0.262   0.7935  
type2wet       -0.107377   1.078726  -0.100   0.9207  
perc.for.100m  -0.002806   0.026807  -0.105   0.9166  
perc.dry.100m  -0.010227   0.036982  -0.277   0.7821  
perc.wet.100m  -0.006486   0.038071  -0.170   0.8647  
count           0.345036   0.153811   2.243   0.0249 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 69.315  on 49  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 63.431  on 43  degrees of freedom
AIC: 77.431
```

*EDIT 1*

Aniko noticed that there may be an interaction between the type2 and species. Indeed!

```
Call:
glm(formula = count ~ type1 + type2 * species + perc.for.100m + 
    perc.dry.100m + perc.wet.100m, family = poisson, data = dej)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.0859  -1.1350  -0.1947   0.7109   2.7470  

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)             -0.357165   0.559987  -0.638  0.52360    
type1intensive           0.196699   0.191960   1.025  0.30551    
type2wet                 0.704769   0.429087   1.642  0.10049    
speciessinapis           1.145132   0.306847   3.732  0.00019 ***
perc.for.100m            0.003741   0.008277   0.452  0.65130    
perc.dry.100m            0.010952   0.010750   1.019  0.30829    
perc.wet.100m            0.007467   0.011596   0.644  0.51960    
type2wet:speciessinapis -0.962811   0.394038  -2.443  0.01455 *
```

*EDIT 2*

After removing the non significant terms (assuming I found the global maximum for the sake of data dredging) the story gets another twist into the right direction.

```
Call:
glm(formula = count ~ type2 * species, family = poisson, data = dej)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.7080  -1.1617  -0.1582   0.6979   3.1599  

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)               0.1542     0.2673   0.577  0.56408    
type2wet                  0.6821     0.3237   2.107  0.03508 *  
speciessinapis            1.1451     0.3068   3.732  0.00019 ***
type2wet:speciessinapis  -0.9628     0.3940  -2.443  0.01455 *
```

Comment: The plot suggests that the effect of wet/dry is different for the two species. How about a `species:type2` interaction term?

Comment: @Aniko, you are very observant. The interaction term is indeed significant. The two species seem to be mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following Nick Sabbe's answer, here is the simplest GLMM solution I can come up with:

```
dej$location <- factor(rep(1:25,2))
library(lme4)
glmer(count ~ type1 + type2*species + 
   perc.for.100m + perc.dry.100m + perc.wet.100m + 
   (1|location), family = poisson, data = dej)
```

It would be a good idea to check for overdispersion too.

For your picture, I would try

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dej,aes(x=type2,y=count))+stat_sum(aes(size=..n..))+
   facet_grid(.~species)
```

mainly for the advantage of `stat_sum`, which will easily show where you have a lot of overplotting (more simply you could try jittering)

Answer (score 5):

You indicate yourself that your measurements are not independent (you measure both species' abundance from the same locations). As such, you should correct for repeated measurements.

Try lmer from the lme4 package.